# Overriding min-height property

Tags: html, css

If possible, how can I override a `min-height` property of a class for a particular div?

Example:

```css
.someclass {
  min-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="someclass">
  -- content --
</div>
```

I have tried using something like `style="min-height:100px!important;"` on the div but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

it is very bad habit to use `!important` declarations in your standard stylesheets. Avoid it at all costs, because it breaks the cascading nature of the stylesheets.

Use a [more specific selector](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) to override previous styles.

To reset styles to the default, use `auto|inherit|0` depending on the attribute. For `min-height` it's `0`. CSS3 introduces the special value `inital` which should be preferably used - but unfortunately it has limited [IE support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-initial-value).

In your case `min-height:100px;` in a selector with higher specificity (either id or inline style - preferably not the latter) should do the trick.

```js
let div = document.querySelector("#morespecific");

div.innerHTML = "This div has its min-height set to: "+window.getComputedStyle(div).minHeight;
```

```css
.someclass{
    min-height:200px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
#morespecific{
     min-height:100px;
     border-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="morespecific" class="someclass">
-- content --
</div>
```

Comment: need to override min-height: 200px.

min-height:auto is also not working

Comment: thanks for your solution, I was omitting px after 100px. that happens sometime when figure is coming dynamically

Comment: `auto` is not a valid property for `min-height`.

Comment: I never said it was;)

Answer (score 6):

I couldn't find any better answer than to just use 0 to override min stuff, and use something like 1000% to override max stuff.

Comment: Yep! this is the standard way to reset "min-*" CSS properties.

Comment: This is the logic answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

An `!important` flag needs to go inside the semi-colon, like this:

```
.someclass {min-height: 200px !important;}
```

Furthermore, you shouldn't really be using `!important` flags if you can help it. An overriding rule needs to be more specific than the original rule.

I think you need to read up on [specificity and inheritance](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/04/07/css-specificity-and-inheritance/).

Comment: used important to discard this solution
and I need to override property of min-height: 200px. It is already using 200px, so that won't help

Comment: .someclass with other properties is not set for this div only. Thats why need to override it :)

Comment: You're not giving us enough information from the outset to give you a decent answer. Try finding the element you want to style. It may look like `<div class="someclass"></div>`. Try adding another class to it, so it looks like `<div class="someclass anotherclass"></div>`. Then you can use `.someclass.anotherclass {declaration: value;}`.

Comment: To be clear, this is just an example. I'm not advocating the use of meaningless class names like 'someclass' or 'anotherclass'.

Comment: sure, I am using someclass as an example too.

Answer (score 0):

Inline styles override CSS styles, so

```
<div class="someclass" style="height: 50px;">...</div>
```

overrides the rule in your stylesheet. However, it's generally not a good solution to fix this problem. The preferred solution would be to use a selector with a higher specificity in your external css.

Comment: same, I wa omitting px from the property so the correct solution would be 

<div class="someclass" style="height: 50px;"> -- content -- </div>. Thank you for answering.